# postgresql pg_dumpall restore one database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
# rpm -q postgresql
postgresql-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64
#
```

I used following [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.6: pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-dumpall.html) to take dump all databases

> $ pg_dumpall > db.out

from what I understand, following will restore *all* databases:

> $ psql -f db.out postgres

my goal is, I need to restore just a *one* (single) database from that entire dump, how does one accomplish this task?

Comment: What exactly you need from the output of `pg_dumpall`, apart from the DB in question?  Isn't it easier just to dump a single DB using `pg_dump`?

Answer (score 1):

Your dump is in SQL format. Just open your db.out file remove what's for other databases.

Comment: that would be too much, i want better solution then editing dump file, what's other way of accomplishing same thing? perhaps changing `pg_dumpall` to `pg_dump`? but then I need to keep track of each database name, which also not ideal...

Comment: Then you have to use `pg_dump` for each and every database you want to dump to a file. You can list all you databases with `psql`.
Don't forget to use `pg_dumpall` with `-g` option to save roles and tablespaces.